# Error with Action Listeners

Tags: java, user-interface

so I made this Java GUI which basically solves SUVAT questions (for those of you who are unfamiliar with SUVAT, it basically tells you an approximate value of how much a car will acceleration given its speed/time, or finding how high a ball will go with a given speed etc. You use it mehcanics). 
I know there are flaws in my program such as only producing integer variables (just to keep things tidy) so the answer may be rounded up. The layout isn't good but I just started to program recently.
The GUI loads up perfectly but when the user presses the calculate button, thats when it crashes. Im suspecting its something got to do with the action listener on the button as I think I made it a bit complicated then it was supposed to.

The user basically chooses what he wants to solve (e.g. if I wanted to find the acceleration of a car, then I would check the acceleration radio button, and type in the given variables I know (i.e. initial velocity is 15, final velocity is 30, time is 2 therefore the acceleration should be 7.5 (8 in this case since ints were used). The program choses the most suitable equation to use to find the variable you want to know.

This is the code:

```
   import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class GUImain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GUI go = new GUI();
    go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    go.setSize(400,400);
    go.setVisible(true);

}

} 

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JTextField DISPLACEMENT = new JTextField("Displacement", 20);
JTextField INITALVELOCITY = new JTextField("Intital Velocity", 20);
JTextField FINALVELOCITY = new JTextField("Final Velocity", 20);
JTextField ACCELERATION = new JTextField("Acceleration", 20);
JTextField TIME = new JTextField("Time");

JRadioButton S = new JRadioButton("Displacement", true);
JRadioButton U = new JRadioButton("Inital Velocity", false);
JRadioButton V = new JRadioButton("Final Velocity", false);
JRadioButton A = new JRadioButton("Acceleration", false);
JRadioButton T = new JRadioButton("Time", false);
ButtonGroup VARIABLEFINDER;
JButton CALCULATE = new JButton("Calculate");

GUI() {
    super("SUVAT Solver");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(DISPLACEMENT);
    add(INITALVELOCITY);
    add(FINALVELOCITY);
    add(ACCELERATION);
    add(TIME);
    add(CALCULATE);

    add(S);
    add(U);
    add(V);
    add(A);
    add(T);

    VARIABLEFINDER = new ButtonGroup();
    VARIABLEFINDER.add(S);
    VARIABLEFINDER.add(U);
    VARIABLEFINDER.add(V);
    VARIABLEFINDER.add(A);
    VARIABLEFINDER.add(T);

    // Adding Listeners to the RadioButtons
    CALCULATE.addActionListener(this);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String dis = DISPLACEMENT.getText();
    int SS = Integer.parseInt(dis);

    String initv = INITALVELOCITY.getText();
    int UU = Integer.parseInt(initv);

    String finalv = FINALVELOCITY.getText();
    int VV = Integer.parseInt(finalv);

    String acc = ACCELERATION.getText();
    int AA = Integer.parseInt(acc);

    String timme = TIME.getText();
    int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);

    // CALCULATING DISPLACEMENT
    if (e.getSource() == CALCULATE && S.isSelected()) {
        if (FINALVELOCITY.getText().equals("Final Velocity")) {
            SS = (int) ((int) (UU * TT) + (0.5 * AA * (TT * TT)));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The displacement claulcated is " + SS);
        } else if (ACCELERATION.getText().equals("Acceleration")) {
            SS = (int) 0.5 * (UU + VV) * TT;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The displacement claulcated is " + SS);
        } else if (INITALVELOCITY.getText().equals("Inital Velocity")) {
            SS = (int) ((VV * TT) - (0.5 * AA * (TT * TT)));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The displacement claulcated is " + SS);
        } else if (TIME.getText().equals("Time")) {
            SS = (((VV * VV) - (UU * UU)) / (2 * AA));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The displacement claulcated is " + SS);
        }

    }
    // CALCULATING THE INITAL VELOCITY
    if (e.getSource() == CALCULATE && U.isSelected()) {
        if (FINALVELOCITY.getText().equals("Final Velocity")) {
            UU = (int) ((SS - (0.5 * AA * (TT * TT))) / (TT));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The intial velocity claulcated is " + UU);
        } else if (ACCELERATION.getText().equals("Acceleration")) {
            UU = ((2 * SS) / TT) - VV;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The intial velocity claulcated is " + UU);
        } else if (TIME.getText().equals("Time")) {
            UU = (int) Math.sqrt(((VV * VV) - (2 * AA * SS)));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The intial velocity claulcated is " + UU);
        } else if (DISPLACEMENT.getText().equals("Displacement")) {
            UU = (AA * TT) - VV;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The intial velocity claulcated is " + UU);
        }
    }

    // CALCULATING THE FINAL VELOCITY
    if (e.getSource() == CALCULATE && V.isSelected()) {
        if (INITALVELOCITY.getText().equals("Inital Velocity")) {
            VV = (int) ((SS + (0.5 * AA * (TT * TT))) / TT);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The final velocity claulcated is " + VV);
        } else if (TIME.getText().equals("Time")) {
            VV = (int) Math.sqrt(((UU * UU) + (2 * AA * SS)));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The final velocity claulcated is " + VV);
        } else if (DISPLACEMENT.getText().equals("Displacement")) {
            VV = (AA * TT) + UU;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The final velocity claulcated is " + VV);
        } else if (ACCELERATION.getText().equals("Acceleration")) {
            VV = ((2 * SS) / TT) - UU;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The final velocity claulcated is " + VV);
        }
    }

    // CALCULATING THE ACCELERATION
    if (e.getSource() == CALCULATE && A.isSelected()) {
        if (INITALVELOCITY.getText().equals("Inital Velocity")) {
            AA = (int) ((SS - (VV * TT)) / (-0.5 * (TT * TT)));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The acceleration claulcated is " + AA);
        } else if (TIME.getText().equals("Time")) {
            AA = (((VV * VV) - (UU * UU)) / (2 * SS));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The acceleration claulcated is " + AA);
        } else if (DISPLACEMENT.getText().equals("Displacement")) {
            AA = (VV - UU) / TT;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The acceleration claulcated is " + AA);
        } else if (FINALVELOCITY.getText().equals("Final Velocity")) {
            VV = (int) ((SS - (UU * TT)) / (0.5 * (TT * TT)));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The acceleration claulcated is " + AA);
        }
    }

    // CALCULATING THE TIME
    if (CALCULATE.getAction() && A.isSelected()) {
        if (INITALVELOCITY.getText().equals("Inital Velocity")) {
            AA = (int) ((SS - (VV * TT)) / (-0.5 * (TT * TT)));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "havent done the time calculations yet");
        } else if (TIME.getText().equals("Time")) {
            AA = (((VV * VV) - (UU * UU)) / (2 * SS));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "havent done the time calculations yet");
        } else if (DISPLACEMENT.getText().equals("Displacement")) {
            AA = (VV - UU) / TT;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "havent done the time calculations yet");
        } else if (FINALVELOCITY.getText().equals("Final Velocity")) {
            VV = (int) ((SS - (UU * TT)) / (0.5 * (TT * TT)));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "havent done the time calculations yet");
        }
    }

    }

 }
```

I think the error is coming when say for someone wants to find the acceleration using the equation that doesnt contain displacement in it ((V-U)/T), the compiler is still recogizing the default text in the textfield as a string and converting the string into an int since when the calculate button is clicked, everything in the textfield gets converted into a int and my arguments in the action listeners are quite specific.

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Displacement"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at GUI.actionPerformed(GUI.java:66)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT = Thanks Boris the spider, you made me realize that I was trying to convert a string into a int where that string did not contain any numbers. Silly me. Thats quite embarassing. That was the problem

Anyways, the program runs fine, gives rounded answers as its supposed to do. But im pretty sure that I dragged the code for the application a bit too much. This is the working part action part listener of the working code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



    // CALCULATING DISPLACEMENT
    if (e.getSource() == CALCULATE && S.isSelected()) {
        if (FINALVELOCITY.getText().equals("")) {
            String initv = INITALVELOCITY.getText();
            int UU = Integer.parseInt(initv);
            String timme = TIME.getText();
            int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);
            String acc = ACCELERATION.getText();
            int AA = Integer.parseInt(acc);

            int SS = (int) ((int) (UU * TT) + (0.5 * AA * (TT * TT)));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The displacement claulcated is " + SS);
        } else if (ACCELERATION.getText().equals("")) {
            String timme = TIME.getText();
            int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);
            String finalv = FINALVELOCITY.getText();
            int VV = Integer.parseInt(finalv);
            String initv = INITALVELOCITY.getText();
            int UU = Integer.parseInt(initv);

            int SS = (int) 0.5 * (UU + VV) * TT;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The displacement claulcated is " + SS);
        } else if (INITALVELOCITY.getText().equals("")) {
            String timme = TIME.getText();
            int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);
            String acc = ACCELERATION.getText();
            int AA = Integer.parseInt(acc);
            String finalv = FINALVELOCITY.getText();
            int VV = Integer.parseInt(finalv);

            int SS = (int) ((VV * TT) - (0.5 * AA * (TT * TT)));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The displacement claulcated is " + SS);

        } else if (TIME.getText().equals("")) {

            String finalv = FINALVELOCITY.getText();
            int VV = Integer.parseInt(finalv);
            String initv = INITALVELOCITY.getText();
            int UU = Integer.parseInt(initv);
            String acc = ACCELERATION.getText();
            int AA = Integer.parseInt(acc);

            int SS = (((VV * VV) - (UU * UU)) / (2 * AA));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The displacement claulcated is " + SS);
        }

    }
    // CALCULATING THE INITAL VELOCITY
    if (e.getSource() == CALCULATE && U.isSelected()) {
        if (FINALVELOCITY.getText().equals("")) {

            String dis = DISPLACEMENT.getText();
            int SS = Integer.parseInt(dis);
            String acc = ACCELERATION.getText();
            int AA = Integer.parseInt(acc);
            String timme = TIME.getText();
            int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);


            int UU = (int) ((SS - (0.5 * AA * (TT * TT))) / (TT));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The intial velocity claulcated is " + UU);


        } else if (ACCELERATION.getText().equals("")) {
            String timme = TIME.getText();
            int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);
            String dis = DISPLACEMENT.getText();
            int SS = Integer.parseInt(dis);
            String finalv = FINALVELOCITY.getText();
            int VV = Integer.parseInt(finalv);


            int UU = ((2 * SS) / TT) - VV;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The intial velocity claulcated is " + UU);
        } 


        else if (TIME.getText().equals("")) {

            String finalv = FINALVELOCITY.getText();
            int VV = Integer.parseInt(finalv);
            String acc = ACCELERATION.getText();
            int AA = Integer.parseInt(acc);
            String dis = DISPLACEMENT.getText();
            int SS = Integer.parseInt(dis);

            int UU = (int) Math.sqrt(((VV * VV) - (2 * AA * SS)));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The intial velocity claulcated is " + UU);
        } else if (DISPLACEMENT.getText().equals("")) {
            String acc = ACCELERATION.getText();
            int AA = Integer.parseInt(acc);
            String finalv = FINALVELOCITY.getText();
            int VV = Integer.parseInt(finalv);
            String timme = TIME.getText();
            int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);

            int UU = (AA * TT) - VV;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The intial velocity claulcated is " + UU);
        }
    }

    // CALCULATING THE FINAL VELOCITY
    if (e.getSource() == CALCULATE && V.isSelected()) {



        if (INITALVELOCITY.getText().equals("")) {
            String dis = DISPLACEMENT.getText();
            int SS = Integer.parseInt(dis);
            String acc = ACCELERATION.getText();
            int AA = Integer.parseInt(acc);
            String timme = TIME.getText();
            int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);


            int VV = (int) ((SS + (0.5 * AA * (TT * TT))) / TT);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The final velocity claulcated is " + VV);
        } else if (TIME.getText().equals("")) {
            String acc = ACCELERATION.getText();
            int AA = Integer.parseInt(acc);String dis = DISPLACEMENT.getText();
            int SS = Integer.parseInt(dis);
            String initv = INITALVELOCITY.getText();
            int UU = Integer.parseInt(initv);

            int VV = (int) Math.sqrt(((UU * UU) + (2 * AA * SS)));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The final velocity claulcated is " + VV);
        } else if (DISPLACEMENT.getText().equals("")) {
            String initv = INITALVELOCITY.getText();
            int UU = Integer.parseInt(initv);
            String timme = TIME.getText();
            int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);
            String acc = ACCELERATION.getText();
            int AA = Integer.parseInt(acc);

            int VV = (AA * TT) + UU;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The final velocity claulcated is " + VV);
        } else if (ACCELERATION.getText().equals("")) {
            String timme = TIME.getText();
            int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);
            String dis = DISPLACEMENT.getText();
            int SS = Integer.parseInt(dis);
            String initv = INITALVELOCITY.getText();
            int UU = Integer.parseInt(initv);

            int VV = ((2 * SS) / TT) - UU;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The final velocity claulcated is " + VV);
        }
    }

    // CALCULATING THE ACCELERATION
    if (e.getSource() == CALCULATE && A.isSelected()) {
        if (INITALVELOCITY.getText().equals("")) {
            String dis = DISPLACEMENT.getText();
            int SS = Integer.parseInt(dis);
            String finalv = FINALVELOCITY.getText();
            int VV = Integer.parseInt(finalv);
            String timme = TIME.getText();
            int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);

            int AA = (int) ((SS - (VV * TT)) / (-0.5 * (TT * TT)));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The acceleration claulcated is " + AA);
        } else if (TIME.getText().equals("")) {
            String dis = DISPLACEMENT.getText();
            int SS = Integer.parseInt(dis);
            String initv = INITALVELOCITY.getText();
            int UU = Integer.parseInt(initv);
            String finalv = FINALVELOCITY.getText();
            int VV = Integer.parseInt(finalv);

            int AA = (((VV * VV) - (UU * UU)) / (2 * SS));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The acceleration claulcated is " + AA);
        } else if (DISPLACEMENT.getText().equals("")) {

            String finalv = FINALVELOCITY.getText();
            int VV = Integer.parseInt(finalv);
            String initv = INITALVELOCITY.getText();
            int UU = Integer.parseInt(initv);
            String timme = TIME.getText();
            int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);

            int AA = (VV - UU) / TT;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The acceleration claulcated is " + AA);
        } else if (FINALVELOCITY.getText().equals("")) {
            String initv = INITALVELOCITY.getText();
            int UU = Integer.parseInt(initv);
            String dis = DISPLACEMENT.getText();
            int SS = Integer.parseInt(dis);
            String timme = TIME.getText();
            int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);
            int AA = (int) ((SS - (UU * TT)) / (0.5 * (TT * TT)));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The acceleration claulcated is " + AA);
        }
    }
```

Im pretty sure I could've made the methods thats converts the string into integers as an object of a different class so when I want to convert a string from the displacement textfield to an int, i could just call that object?

Comment: Crashes is about the most vague description you could give. If you want help then post the strack trace of the error. Further please stick to [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) - without these the code is impossible to read. Classes should be in `PascalCase` (not block caps) and variables should be in `LowerCamelCase` (not block caps).

Comment: it's probably due to your getAction() call in the last if statement

Comment: The error doesn't get any clearer - _java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Displacement"_. You are trying to parse the `String` "Displacement" to an `Integer` - this obviously doesn't work. Consider using a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) and a [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) in a [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) rather than placing the labels _inside_ the input fields.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue was resolved by *Boris the Spider* in one of the comments.

Concerning the implicit question in the edited part:

> Im pretty sure I could've made the methods thats converts the string into integers as an object of a different class so when I want to convert a string from the displacement textfield to an int, i could just call that object?

Indeed, the code in its current form is not really elegant. Mainly because it is very repetitive. There are several options for improving this. One step could be a method like

```
private static int parseIntFrom(JTextField textField, String name)
{
    String string = textField.getText().trim();
    try 
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(string);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "The "+name+" is not a valid integer: "+string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This method could then replace your highly repetitive parsing code, and by the way, introduce a first step of "error handling" by showing a message when the input was invalid:

```
// Remove this:
// String timme = TIME.getText();
// int TT = Integer.parseInt(timme);

// Becomes
int TT = parseIntFrom(TIME, "time");
```

Alternatively, the `JFormattedTextField` that *Boris the Spider* mentioned could be used to make sure that only valid integer values may be entered in the first place.

I assume that the complex if/else-constructs could be simplified further, but one would have to know the intended workflow (and possibly the formulas that are used there) to give more detailed hints. The only recommendation until now is the obvious one to at least introduce some methods with "speaking" names, like

```
private void calculateDisplacement() { ... }    
private void calculateAcceleration() { ... }
...
```

that are called from the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: Yeah those are some pretty useful ways of of getting rid of the reoccurring code. This is what I did since I found it much simplier:
From displacement to int, use this method:
public int STOINT() {
  if (DISPLACEMENT.getText().equals("")) {
   int SS = 0;
   return SS;

  } else {
   String dis = DISPLACEMENT.getText();
   int SS = Integer.parseInt(dis);
   return SS;
  }

 }
and then in the class, write this method:
int s = STOINT();

So now I can just write the equations using integers.